# Is there an implementation of inductive graphs in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, directed-acyclic-graphs

By "inductive graphs", I mean as a purely functional data structure, e.g. as described in this paper: web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf

More specifically, I'm only interested in DAGs implemented in this way, although I imagine the general approach would be similar.

Comment: In general, if something is implemented in Erlang you can easily use it from Elixir.  I hope one day the converse is true as well.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen anything like this for Elixir, but there is an Erlang implementation: [digraph](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html).

Comment: Another vote for digraph! We simply use it from Elixir too. Although it is worth noting digraph uses ETS and it is not purely functional.

Comment: Thanks. I've written an introductory blog post on how to use Erlang's digraph from Elixir: http://blog.jordan-dimov.com/elixir-graph-data-structures-with-erlangs-digraph/